# A conservative (2D) vector field that is perpendicular to the unit square on the boundary of unit square?

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm trying to test a PDE solver and I'm wondering if there is any 2D vector field that satisfies the following on the domain $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1]$:

$$\text{curl} \;\mathbf{u} = 0 \;\;\;\forall \mathbf{x} \in \Omega$$
$$\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{t} = 0 \;\;\;\forall \mathbf{x} \in \partial\Omega$$

where $\mathbf{t}$ is the tangential vector to $\partial\Omega$.

i.e. I'm looking for a vector field that is conservative and also, on the boundary of the domain (the unit square) is perpendicular to the boundary.

Is this possible? I can come up with several examples for each separate condition, but none for both.

Comment: How continuous should your field be? What about the corners?

Comment: @christianblatter I'm honestly not entirely sure but I'll give anything a try at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x,y):=\sin(\pi x)\>\sin(\pi y)\qquad\bigl((x,y\in\Omega\bigr)$$
and put
$${\bf u}(x,y):=\nabla f(x,y)=\bigl(\pi\cos(\pi x)\>\sin(\pi y),\ \pi\sin(\pi x)\>\cos(\pi y)\bigr)\ .$$
Then ${\rm curl}({\bf u})\equiv0$ and
$${\bf u}(0,y)=\bigl(\pi\sin(\pi y),0\bigr)\ne{\bf 0}\qquad(0< y<1)\ ,$$
and similarly for the other three edges of $\Omega$.

Comment: Great, thanks!!